# Using multiple terminals on a remote machine using a single SSH connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, ssh

I'm running a process on a remote server through SSH on a certain port. The process is basically a TCP server waiting (listening) for a connection. So as long as it is running I cannot use the terminal as it is a blocking application.

I want to run another application (a TCP client) through the same instance of SSH connection to connect to that TCP server. I used screen to detach the first process (TCP Server) and connect to the server but then I could not see the output of the TCP server application.

Is there a way to emulate two terminals on a remote machine using SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution to this problem. Basically below is a link that explains how can I achieve exactly what I needed. That is, opening multiple terminals using a single SSH connection.

http://idnotfound.wordpress.com/2008/01/14/multiple-terminals-in-a-single-ssh-session/

In short we can use the following procedure:

`$ ssh -X mylogin@remotemachine gnome-terminal
Password: ...
[Ctrl+Z]
$ bg
$ exit`

Press Ctrl+Shift+N to open a new terminal.

EDIT: Or just use `screen`. Sigh..